# SignalR Hub not connecting

Tags: javascript, c#, html, signalr

I'm trying to create a SignalR application but I cannot connect to my hub.

Here is my following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="display">Display</button>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <input id="Name" type="Text">
    <input id="Content" type="Text">
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {
            messageArr = [];

            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (id, name, content) {
                var message = { ID: id, Name: name, Content: content };
                messageArr.push(message);
            };

            $('#display').click(function() {
                window.alert(messageArr);
            });

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#send').click(function () {
                    window.alert("Sent");
                    chat.server.send(0, document.getElementById("Name").value, document.getElementById("Content"));

                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Hub:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(int id, String name, String content)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(id, name, content);
        }
    }
}
```

Owin Startup Class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPI.Startup))]

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
         }
     }
}
```

When I run this through Visual Studio 2013, I click the send button and no alert comes up telling me I've pressed the button. Also, when I click the display button later, the messageArr array is still empty. What can I change to make this actually work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure how but I seemed to have fixed my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>

</head>
<body>
<button id="display"onclick="displayMessage()">Display</button>
<button id="send">Send</button>
<input id="Name" type="Text">
<input id="Content" type="Text">
<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    messageArr = [];
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (id, name, content) {
            var message = { ID: id, Name: name, Content: content };
            messageArr.push(message);
        };


        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#send').click(function () {
                chat.server.send(0, document.getElementById("Name").value, document.getElementById("Content").value);

            });
        });
    });
    function displayMessage() {
        window.alert(messageArr);
    }

</script>
```

If anyone could explain to me how this fixed my problem that would be helpful.